Qt IOS: Get device Model and Serial Number
I have an Qt app that is going to run on an iPad. I need to find a way to get as much info on the device as I can, namely:;
Serial Number (This would be the most important)
Model (Second most important)
And if Possible:
Storage Size,
Processor Model
Amount of RAM available.
Is there a way that I can get this information by using Qt?

You will not be able to get the serial number for privacy reasons.

I'd assume. But wanted to confirm. Thank you!

SERIAL NUMBER
Unfortunately, Apple has strict security measures in place to prevent direct access to device serial numbers on iOS devices. This is primarily to protect user privacy and security.
If you need a unique identifier for a device, consider using the following alternatives:
IdentifierForVendor: This property of UIDevice provides a unique identifier that is associated with a specific vendor (e.g., your app's organization). It's suitable for tracking usage within your own app ecosystem.
AdvertisingIdentifier: This property of ASIdentifierManager provides a unique identifier that can be used for advertising purposes. However, users can reset it, so it might not be suitable for long-term tracking.
UUID: You can generate a Universally Unique Identifier (UUID) using the UUID class. This provides a random, globally unique identifier that can be used for various purposes.
Recommendation: UUID (Store in Keychain w.r.t Bundle ID)
class func generateUUID() -> String {
            var uuid = UUID().uuidString
            uuid = uuid.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
            let index: String.Index = uuid.index(uuid.startIndex, offsetBy: 32)
            uuid = String(uuid[..<index])
            return uuid
 }

DEVICE MODEL
let device = UIDevice.current
print("Device model: \(device.model)")

Hope this will help you.

Thank you answer. My app is a Qt app. So I'm not really sure how to get any of the values you mentioned. It seems I could use the UUID. I'll look into it.
